# Can't render page with SSR routes

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to get SSR working within my Meteor app with routes with very little success. I'm currently getting the error below, however, I'm not sure what the problem is relating to. I think this is a react error. Sorry for the noob question.

**Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `context` is marked as required in `StaticRouter`, but its value is `undefined`. in StaticRouter**

Path: `imports/startup/server.js`

```
import ServerRoutes from './server-routes';

onPageLoad(sink => {
  sink.renderIntoElementById(
    'app',
    renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={sink.request.url}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    )
  );
});
```

Path: `imports/startup/server-routes.js`

```
const ServerPage = () => <h1>Server index.</h1>;

const myServerRoutes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/ServerPage" component={ServerPage} />
  </Switch>
);
export default myServerRoutes;
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/StaticRouter.md#staticrouter you're not passing the `context` prop